# Combining 2 queries to improve efficiency

Tags: postgresql, join, postgis

I'm trying to combine 2 queries.  They worked well in small numbers but do not scale.  I have a few tables to store and lookup geometries.

types: identifies a type of geometry, e.g. area of responsibility, country, etc

places: table for geometries

shapes: custom user-drawn shapes.  My example uses points but they could be shapes as well.

user_shapes: lookup table for a user's shapes.

A user might have an area of responsibility (e.g. 2 counties within a state) and they have many points of interest within that shape (e.g. schools, hospitals).  I currently query the list of user shapes (points in my example), then loop and query all places that shape is within. This is fast with small datasets but once a user has 1000 shapes it takes minutes...

Here's schema and example load

```sql
create extension postgis;

create table shapes
(
    uid        serial primary key,
    placeid    int,
    attributes text
);

create table user_shapes
(
    uid     serial primary key,
    userid  int,
    shapeid int
);

create table types
(
    id       int primary key,
    typename varchar(64)
);

create table places
(
    uid    int primary key,
    geom   Geometry(Geometry, 4326),
    name   varchar(256),
    typeid int
);


insert into types values (1, 'Test1'), (2, 'Test2'), (3, 'Test3'), (4, 'shapes');

insert into places values (1, ST_GeomFromText( 'POLYGON((-98.1298828124999 30.2211018524859,-98.6100200346972 30.1764857974889,-99.0761705261207 30.0674176153688,-99.5168561146059 29.8963760406263,-99.9212256584129 29.6672678682823,-100.279322237348 29.3853632993911,-100.582328325183 29.0572043419339,-100.822782906416 28.6904844149233,-100.994765191234 28.2938977980301,-101.094040405008 27.8769585908972,-101.1181640625 27.4497903297842,-101.0665421592 27.0228892179537,-100.940445797691 26.6068658699129,-100.742979888883 26.2121723306567,-100.479006698803 25.8488226973937,-100.155026123467 25.526116768878,-99.7790156398708 25.2523766654583,-99.3602338740256 25.0347062651635,-98.908992622866 24.8787826225248,-98.4364029435771 24.7886873659442,-97.9541015625 24.7667845228744,-97.4739643403027 24.8136494186921,-97.0078138488792 24.9280513371023,-96.567128260394 25.1069905954503,-96.162758716587 25.3457886368502,-95.8046621376517 25.6382277267334,-95.5016560498171 25.9767349293004,-95.2612014685839 26.3526033164037,-95.0892191837659 26.7562419373248,-94.989943969992 27.17744507344,-94.9658203124998 27.6056708264655,-95.0174422157995 28.0303192145639,-95.1435385773088 28.4410006875917,-95.3410044861165 28.8277872574235,-95.6049776761967 29.1814401355829,-95.9289582515325 29.4936096870659,-96.3049687351291 29.7570054282864,-96.7237505009743 29.9655355072107,-97.1749917521338 30.1144164316408,-97.6475814314228 30.2002546452876,-98.1298828124999 30.2211018524859))', 4326), 'TestShape1', 1);
insert into places values (2, ST_GeomFromText( 'POLYGON((-71.4990234375 44.1506811597809,-71.7273481296673 44.0881234893864,-71.9392299157485 44.000583537307,-72.1294515629748 43.8901120882822,-72.2933291830822 43.7593108779519,-72.426827565185 43.611280141244,-72.5266595360598 43.449554089394,-72.5903669012608 43.2780247437519,-72.6163809740237 43.1008549350394,-72.6040612015417 42.9223817430893,-72.5537109375 42.7470121731807,-72.4665699725024 42.5791133994505,-72.3447840063114 42.4229004057557,-72.191351813599 42.2823242705718,-72.0100514041622 42.160964629649,-71.8053469957826 42.0619299714262,-71.5822790903699 41.9877693514093,-71.3463403600749 41.9403988437129,-71.1033403994735 41.9210455875073,-70.8592626740661 41.9302116552574,-70.6201171875 41.9676592036782,-70.3917924953327 42.0324175128309,-70.1799107092515 42.1228116260047,-69.9896890620251 42.2365114279472,-69.8258114419178 42.3705991953448,-69.692313059815 42.521652969576,-69.5924810889402 42.6858425770573,-69.5287737237392 42.859034784005,-69.5027596509763 43.0369039325835,-69.5150794234583 43.2150444606988,-69.5654296875 43.3890819391175,-69.6525706524976 43.5547796344738,-69.7743566186886 43.7081380822424,-69.927788811401 43.8454856814533,-70.1090892208378 43.963558853951,-70.3137936292174 44.0595708011318,-70.5368615346301 44.131268305133,-70.7728002649251 44.1769763363557,-71.0158002255265 44.1956304357506,-71.2598779509339 44.1867969431929,-71.4990234375 44.1506811597809))', 4326), 'TestShape2', 2);
insert into places values (3, ST_GeomFromText( 'POLYGON((-80.098813442836 38.5878864978247,-83.493588833461 35.9390929090424,-80.164731411586 33.1432931593309,-76.769956020961 35.8857049791972,-80.098813442836 38.5878864978247))', 4326), 'TestShape3', 3);
insert into places values (4, ST_GeomFromText( 'POLYGON((-78.917216444721 39.729841900827,-79.2823511633174 39.4873369494543,-80.037802305241 40.0197256611727,-79.1060792302019 40.4139164970826,-78.917216444721 39.729841900827))', 4326), 'TestShape4', 1);
insert into places values (5, ST_GeomFromText( 'POLYGON((-80.483334927211 36.665107050558,-80.4075854886107 35.8502643287867,-79.5703148345613 36.311627828202,-80.483334927211 36.665107050558))', 4326), 'TestShape5', 2);
insert into places values (6, ST_GeomFromText( 'POLYGON((-77.528012661586 36.5769309426404,-80.428403286586 37.8021816604304,-81.834653286586 36.6122134882567,-81.834653286586 36.3648971593563,-78.978207974086 35.8322810334427,-77.528012661586 36.5769309426404))', 4326), 'TestShape6', 3);
insert into places values (7, ST_GeomFromText( 'POLYGON((-122.6513671875 46.7398605996926,-122.91661093062 46.6401353655222,-123.155846062572 46.5129093601057,-123.363181820434 46.3611356528843,-123.533512909737 46.1883660663991,-123.662645213766 45.9986818563536,-123.747399066633 45.7966101552473,-123.785687547196 45.5870265739044,-123.776567865991 45.3750449722479,-123.720264579838 45.1658961419227,-123.6181640625 44.964797930331,-123.472780367567 44.7768201074751,-123.287693324109 44.6067479577975,-123.067460389405 44.4589490961483,-122.817504429216 44.3372482984851,-122.543980188842 44.24481516029,-122.253622742854 44.1840691280452,-121.953581655214 44.156605895232,-121.651244933277 44.1631483421157,-121.354057110538 44.2035241772225,-121.0693359375 44.2766712737752,-120.80409219438 44.3806704634695,-120.564857062428 44.5128043349578,-120.357521304566 44.6696394661413,-120.187190215263 44.8471285713291,-120.058057911234 45.0407283265604,-119.973304058367 45.245528190382,-119.935015577804 45.4563853819926,-119.944135259009 45.6680613081537,-120.000438545162 45.8753551145765,-120.1025390625 46.0732306254083,-120.247922757433 46.2569336591614,-120.433009800891 46.4220974959362,-120.653242735595 46.5648350442146,-120.903198695784 46.6818169489465,-121.176722936158 46.7703354438838,-121.467080382146 46.8283541469921,-121.767121469786 46.8545442163687,-122.069458191723 46.8483073343891,-122.366646014462 46.8097858974134,-122.6513671875 46.7398605996926))', 4326), 'TestShape7', 1);
insert into places values (8, ST_GeomFromText( 'POLYGON((-80.065854458461 37.1044722067269,-80.3284961754118 37.0672901855561,-80.5806129837339 36.9977412307377,-80.8159969308785 36.8974521355201,-81.0288520828726 36.7687772274525,-81.2139372394482 36.6147518207695,-81.3666949897881 36.4390306563497,-81.4833639311049 36.2458115236355,-81.5610712868615 36.0397445867827,-81.5979036440632 35.8258283909771,-81.592954067836 35.6092940814789,-81.5463444331734 35.3954799885599,-81.4592224239694 35.1896993649095,-81.3337332732318 34.9971046504341,-81.1729669403265 34.8225521246417,-80.9808820259224 34.6704711372823,-80.7622082981055 34.5447422438544,-80.5223302297911 34.4485884900247,-80.2671544151307 34.3844837816107,-80.0029641295614 34.3540817554779,-79.736264614711 34.3581678577837,-79.4736228977602 34.3966364779743,-79.2215060894381 34.4684940272027,-78.9861221422935 34.5718878412822,-78.7732669902994 34.7041597863191,-78.5881818337238 34.8619225048397,-78.4354240833839 35.0411554134308,-78.3187551420671 35.2373168952427,-78.2410477863105 35.4454686581028,-78.2042154291088 35.6604079743436,-78.209165005336 35.8768034887456,-78.2557746399985 36.0893304656965,-78.3428966492026 36.2928017178254,-78.4683857999402 36.4822909729945,-78.6291521328455 36.6532460408648,-78.8212370472496 36.801589775715,-79.0399107750665 36.9238074419199,-79.2797888433809 37.0170196237633,-79.5349646580413 37.0790402466144,-79.7991549436106 37.1084195732648,-80.065854458461 37.1044722067269))', 4326), 'TestShape8', 2);


-- shapes
insert into places values (9, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-80.164731411586 36.3472015079821)', 4326), 'Point1', 4);
insert into places values (10, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-79.3117894681326 40.0200792538592)', 4326), 'Point2', 4);
insert into places values (11, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-83.8141194159315 38.1564844469837)', 4326), 'Point3', 4);
insert into places values (12, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-80.0921933257511 38.0147349776936)', 4326), 'Point4', 4);
insert into places values (13, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-84.59452327355 34.1843301044122)', 4326), 'Point5', 4);
insert into places values (14, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-81.5329389090467 36.4374419989559)', 4326), 'Point6', 4);

insert into shapes (placeid, attributes) values (9, 'something about point1'), (10, 'something about point2'),
                                                (11, 'something about point3'), (12, 'something about point4'),
                                                (13, 'something about point5'), (14, 'something about point6');

insert into user_shapes (userid, shapeid) values (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6);
```

Here are the queries:

```sql
pdb=# select * from shapes s, user_shapes us where s.uid = us.shapeid and us.userid = 1;
uid | placeid |       attributes       | uid | userid | shapeid
-----+---------+------------------------+-----+--------+---------
   1 |       9 | something about point1 |   7 |      1 |       1
   2 |      10 | something about point2 |   8 |      1 |       2
   3 |      11 | something about point3 |   9 |      1 |       3
(3 rows)

-- now I would loop all placeid returned from above query
pdb=# select uid, name, typeid from places where st_contains(geom, (select geom from places where uid = 9)) = true;
uid |    name    | typeid
-----+------------+--------
   3 | TestShape3 |      3
   5 | TestShape5 |      2
   6 | TestShape6 |      3
   8 | TestShape8 |      2
   9 | Point1     |      4
(5 rows)

pdb=# select uid, name, typeid from places where st_contains(geom, (select geom from places where uid = 10)) = true;
 uid |    name    | typeid 
-----+------------+--------
   4 | TestShape4 |      1
  10 | Point2     |      4
(2 rows)

pdb=# select uid, name, typeid from places where st_contains(geom, (select geom from places where uid = 11)) = true;
 uid |  name  | typeid 
-----+--------+--------
  11 | Point3 |      4
(1 row)
```

Is a join even the best approach?  I thought a where in clause would be faster for the second query so I don't have to loop the results but that throws `ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression`

Ideally, the results would look like this:

```sql
 uid | placeid |       attributes       | uid | userid | shapeid | placeuid | title     | typeid | placeuid | title     | typeid | placeuid | title      | typeid | placeuid | title    | typeid  | 
-----+---------+------------------------+-----+--------+---------+----------+-----------+--------+----------+-----------+--------+----------+------------+--------+----------+----------+--------- 
   1 |       9 | something about point1 |   7 |      1 |       1 |        3 | TestShape3|       3|        5 | TestShape5|      2 |        6 | TestShape6 |      3 |        8 |TestShape8|        2|
   1 |      10 | something about point2 |   8 |      1 |       2 |        4 | TestShape4|       1|        10
   1 |      11 | something about point3 |   9 |      1 |       3 |
```

Comment: How exactly do you want to combine these two query results?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Updated post

Comment: Create an index on the shapes.uid, user_shapes.shapeid and user_shapes.userid columns, and a spatial index on the places.geom

Comment: I still don't get it what the criteria is for combining both queries. Where is the `TestShape4` coming from? I don't see it in your second query

Comment: @DanielDemonceau Updated post.  I do have indexes on those columns, I didn't include them in the sql though.  The criteria for the second query is all the placeid's from the first query.  Now I show all the 2nd queries